# How to calculate the difference between two context variables in Django template

Tags: django, templates, models

Consider a model:

```
class TempReport(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    revenue = models.FloatField()
    # Some other fields not relevant to topic
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'temp_report'
        unique_together = (('sale_point', 'date'), ('id', 'sale_point'),)
        @property
        def net_income(self):
            return self.revenue - self.cost
```

My goal is to calculate net income = revenue - cost
The code for the template:

```
<tbody>
                {% for repdata in reporttable %}
                 <tr>
                    <td> {{ repdata.revenue }}</td>
                    <td> {{ repdata.cost }}</td>
                    <td> {{ repdata.net_income}}</td>
                 </tr>
                {% endfor %}
       </tbody>
```

...and the view

```
def tempreport(request):
    reporttable = TempReport.objects.values('id','cost','revenue')
    return render_to_response('report.html',
                            {'reporttable': reporttable},
                             context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I end up with an empty net_income even if no error message is present. Any ideas why this might be caused by ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a property on the model should work. The indentation on your code is incorrect. The property should be a method of the model class, not the Meta class.

```
class TempReport(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    revenue = models.FloatField()
    # Some other fields not relevant to topic
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'temp_report'
        unique_together = (('sale_point', 'date'), ('id', 'sale_point'),)
    @property
    def net_income(self):
        return self.revenue - self.cost
```

In your view, don't use `values()`, because that will return dictionaries rather than model instances, and you won't be able to access the property.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def tempreport(request):
    reporttable = TempReport.objects.all()

    for r in reporttable:
        r.net_income = r.revenue - r.cost
    return render(request, 'report.html', {'reporttable': reporttable})
```

Note I've also updated the view to use `render` instead of the obsolete `render_to_response`.

Comment: No, it does not work for me. Could you please be kind enough to include the view in accordance with what the view I've included in the question ?

Comment: You haven't shown your original view, so I can only guess what the problem is. You probably shouldn't be using `values()`.

Comment: I have edited the question and included the original view for you.

Comment: Well, if I use reporttable = TempReport.objects.all(), then everything's ok. It's a bit off-topic, but if I use objects.all(), how can I include a field 'sale_point__legal_entities__parent_id' which is a field generated by inner-joining several tables?

Comment: You can follow foreign keys with something like `{{ repdata .sale_point.legal_entities.parent_id }}`. You might find [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) useful for cutting down the number of queries. I agree it's off topic, so if you have any further queries it would be better to ask a new question.